# How can I make selector for an imageview to change only the background but not the image source?

Tags: android, xml, imageview

I have an ImageView with both image src and background color set.

This image is into a layout that is the gridview item layout.

I would to create an xml selector that when the item is choosen, the image background change, but the image src not.

Something similar to the main menu of android with icon with text, I want to highlight only the image.

I would not to make an image for each state of the object, I only want to change the background.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/selector_categorie"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/img_0"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text_1"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text_2"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be achieved with a [StateListDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html).

Create a background drawable resource, e.g. `item_background.xml`, in your `/drawable` folder, containing something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:drawable="@color/color1" android:state_pressed="true"/>
  <item android:drawable="@color/color2" android:state_selected="true"/>
  <item android:drawable="@color/color3" android:state_activated="true"/>
  <item android:drawable="@color/color4"/>
</selector>
```

Then provide the color values in your `/values/colors.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <color name="color1">#DDff8800</color>
  <color name="color2">...</color>
  <!-- more colors... -->
</resources>
```

Finally, set that drawable resource as the item background in your layout with `android:background="@drawable/item_background"`.

The `src` image remains untouched.

Comment: Ok, but how I can disable the standard behaviour of the gridview pressed state and use the imageview pressed state?

Comment: If your `GridView` only holds `ImageView`s, they should take focus on touch by default. Otherwise, set the **`focusable`** flag on your ImageView: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:focusable

Comment: I am in second case. If I put focusable I'm not able to click, the clicklistener is not invoked. Maybe I should only disable the standard selector of grid.

Comment: That's right, if you want to differentiate between a click on the `ImageView` and a click on a general item inside your `GridView`, you have to set an extra listener for the `ImageView` clicks. It would also help if you could provide some code in your question, e.g. how the grid elements' item layout looks like.

Comment: I would use gridview.setonitemclicklistener, but highlight only the image when I touch the gridview element. So, I think that the best choice is to disable gridview highlight setting it to #00000000 and adding the selector to the imageview. I done it, but the textviews change theri color when I touch the grid element. Why?

Comment: The `TextView`s change their color because they also have colors depending on their state assigned by default. Just set a fixed `android:color="@color/your_color"` to your TextViews to disable that behavior.