# How to select the image with selected layer on it

Tags: android, image

How to add a layer to the image when is selected like the normal gallery does i.e,

1.When i select the image(Long click on the image to activate selectable mode) there is a blue layer on it indicates that the image is selected

2.When i deselect the image again(Click on image) it appears as a normal image

can please suggest how can i achieve this
[image]

Comment: have you tried with selectors with multiple drawables for imageview.

Comment: Ya tried with selectors but when i tried to apply to the image background..it was appearing under the image but i need above the image

Comment: please show us what you did so far.

Comment: You must make drawable similer how you want , on hover the touch it will replace the new image.. @user3607798

Comment: i dont know how to write the selector for the above scenario can you please suggest

Comment: @user3607798 please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14302940/how-can-i-make-selector-for-an-imageview-to-change-only-the-background-but-not-t

Comment: sorry i already tried with that link but it wasnt appearing on the top layer